# Replacing ":customimage:" from string into image but returns [object Object] in HTML view in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have my function here:

```
    WordColonsToImage(comment) {
        var newcomment = comment.replace(/:wave:\s*/g, <img src={wavinghand} />)
        return newcomment
    }
```

And here is the example:
`WordColonsToImage("Hi! :wave:")` and this returns in HTML: `Hi! [object Object]`

How could I fix this object Object thing?

Comment: I sounded like I am still a newbie at JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.replace(searchValue: string | RegExp, replaceValue: string): string (+3 overloads)` In string.replace function the  replaceValue must be a string format, not an HTML element format so you must change as a string format

```
WordColonsToImage(comment) {
        var newcomment = comment.replace(/:wave:\s*/g, "<img src={wavinghand} />")
        return newcomment
    }
```

if you want to want to render HTML then refer to this example

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const viewImg = () => {
    let comment = "Hi abc";
    var newcomment = comment.replace(
      "abc",
      '<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550355291-bbee04a92027?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8Y2FyfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" />'
    );
    return newcomment;
  };


  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: viewImg()}} />
}
```

[view code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ojjaf9?file=src/App.js)